# How to get run_id in a Javascript-based GitHub action?

Tags: javascript, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm trying to retrieve the run ID from the context object. However, all my attempts are in vain. The output of the following tries is `undefined`. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
    const context = core.getInput('github_context');
    if (context) {
      core.info("Context: " + context)
      core.info(`run id: ${context['run_id']}`)
      core.info(`run id: ${context.run_id}`)
      core.info(`run id: ${context['runId']}`)
      core.info(`run id: ${context.runId}`)
    }
```

When anaysing the output of `core.info("Context: " + context)`, one can see the following:

```
Context: {
  "token": "**",
  "job": "test",
  "run_id": "123",
```

The way I pass the context is `github_context: ${{ toJson(github) }}`

Comment: Yes, you're right. After the conversion, one can access the run ID with `run_id` (not `runId`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` variable is a JSON string, not a Javascript object due to which the problem arises. To access its properties, you will need to parse the JSON string first.

```js
// ...Rest of your code
const contextString = core.getInput('github_context');
if (contextString) {
  const context = JSON.parse(contextString); // <--- this
  core.info("Context: " + contextString)
  core.info(`run id: ${context['run_id']}`)
  core.info(`run id: ${context.run_id}`);
}
```